# Google Dataflow can write to anywhere without permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataflow

I created a service account and assigned the Dataflow developer role, Compute Viewer role, and the Storage Object Admin role to the temporary bucket. Then, I created another bucket with my admin user account(which has the project owner role) named as gs://outputbucket. Finally, I submit a dataflow job with following cmd:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENRTIALS=<path-to-credential>
TMPBUCKET=temporarybucket
OUTBUCKET=outputbucket
PROJECT=myprojectid

python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
  --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt \
  --output gs://$OUTBUCKET/wordcount/outputs \
  --runner DataflowRunner \
  --project $PROJECT \
  --temp_location gs://$TMPBUCKET/tmp/
```

Similarly, I create a Dataflow job from existing Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery template. It can write to any table in the same project without permission. Can anyone explain how could this be possible?

Furthermore, is this a potential security issue according to Google's [Principle of Least Privilege](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely)?

---

Comment: In your code example, are you using your new service account to run your dataflow?

Comment: I set the environmental var GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENRTIALS to the path of service account cred json file, I updated it to the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The service account that you use with this command

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENRTIALS=<path-to-credential>
```

is used for creating the Dataflow pipeline, but it's not used by the pipeline workers.

For this, you have to add the service account email in the option of the pipeline as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options). If not, it's the compute engine service account which is used.

Comment: I think I also find a new concept from GCP called `service controller account`. In short, when try to run a job, if not specified by `--service_account_email=account@name.com`, GCP will use a default `service controller account` that's created by default with the project. And the reason why I see my problem is, the default account has the project editor role assigned. See: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#controller_service_account

Comment: Yes, the default service account is the compute service account (as mentioned in my answer) which has this pattern `<PROJECT_NUMBER>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what service account you are using to run the job or the User (I guess)

As per the Google document, [Dataflow Controller Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#controller_service_account), By default, workers use your project’s Compute Engine service account as the controller service account.